# How update ListView?

Tags: android, listview, mobile, react-native

I have a proplem. I need update ListView with new array, but i see empty ListView instead my items. No error, just white screen... How fix it?

If delete sendMes(), then app work.

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
var ds= new ListView.DataSource({
    rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
});

var Dimensions = require('Dimensions')      //определяем размеры экрана
var {widthScr, heightScr} = Dimensions.get('window')

var messagesArray = [
  {message: "Hello", style: styles.nikkiMes},
  {message: "Okkkk", style: styles.userMes}
];

this.state = {
  messagesSource: ds.cloneWithRows(messagesArray.slice()),
  inputMes: '',
  messagesArray: messagesArray
};}

renderMessages(rowMessages){
return(
    <Text style={rowMessages.style}>{rowMessages.message}</Text>
);}

sendMes(){
var ds= new ListView.DataSource({
    rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
});

this.setState({
  messagesArray: this.state.messagesArray.concat({message: this.inputMes, style: styles.userMes}),
  messagesSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.messagesArray.concat({message: this.inputMes, style: styles.userMes}).slice())
});}

render() {
return (
  <View styyle={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.messagesSource}
      renderRow={this.renderMessages.bind(this)}
    />
    <TextInput
      style={{height: 50}}
      placeholder="Type here..."
      onChangeText={(inputMes) => this.setState({inputMes})}
    />
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.sendMes()}> <Text>Button</Text> </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
);}
```

How i can add new items to ListView?

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding your datasource in sendMes function. To update you ListView just update the state with you new items/data

```
this.setState({
  messagesSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this._generate_new_items()),
});
```

Put above function inside your setMes function and create a new function "_generate_new_items" that will generate new items which will be updated in your ListView. You can have _generate_new_items function something like below:

```
_generate_new_items(){
    var dataBlob = [];
    for (var ii = 0; ii < 100; ii++) {
       dataBlob.push('Row ' + ii);
    }
    return dataBlob;
}
```

For help refer to https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html